# Thread handle validity after thread completion affecting debugging?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, exception

I'm just trying to make sure I have something figured out correctly.

Apparently, when running under a debugger, calling `CloseHandle()` on an invalid handle will cause an exception to be thrown.  Not sure where this behavior is documented, but there are multiple mentions of it on Google.

Well, I'm getting it while debugging, but there is no reason for the handle to be invalid.

Basically the thread is started, then later, it is checked to see if it it is hung

```
auto waitResult = WaitForSingleObject( hThread, 100 );
if ( waitResult == WAIT_TIMEOUT )
{
     // Handle hung thread stuff
     // This branch is not executed and shown only for completeness
}
else
{
    // Thread completed OK stuff
    // Just saves some stuff produced by the thread.
}

// some stuff omitted 

// just prior to procedure exit
if ( hThread != NULL )
{
    CloseHandle( hThread );
    // When running under a debugger, throws a 0xC0000008 here
    // waitResult happens to be zero when this is happening
}
```

Now I wouldn't expect the handle to be invalid, as I just successfully completed a `WaitForSingleObject()` on it.

So is the handle on a thread becoming invalid as the thread terminates defined behavior?  (would seem in danger of race conditions if the handle value got used again )?

Sure I can wrap the `CloseHandle()` with a `try` / `catch`.  But I want to understand what is going on.

I also wouldn't mind know what Microsoft says officially about this `CloseHandle()` throwing a 0xC0000008 while debugging thing.

Comment: What do you do in "Handle hung thread stuff"?

Comment: Microsoft is very concerned about code permitting handle recycling attacks, that's why you get the diagnostic when you have a debugger attached.  Do note that the code you posted is very buggy.  If you have confidence in hThread being valid then testing it for NULL makes no sense at all.  And worse, the // Thread completed OK is highly misleading since you did not actually check that WFSO actually returned WAIT_OBJECT_0.  So the handle can be invalid even *before* this code runs.

Comment: There is a `TerminateThread` in there.  ( I hate it too).  But it should be moot to this question, as that branch is not taken when the exception is thrown. The other branch,"Thread completed OK stuff" just saves some results.

Comment: @infixed `TerminateThread` can leave your whole program in an undefined state as no locks held by the thread are released.  For example if `TerminateThread` is called when the thread is allocating a new heap block then the heap serialisation lock will not be released.

Comment: @HansPassant  Following SE guidelines, I tried to focus on the problem, omitting irrelevancies.  The creation of the thread handle is not shown.  The fact that `WaitForSingleObject` had no problem with it was mentioned., and should establish it was valid at that point  The null check is in cleanup at the end of the procedure, and could be reached by a `goto` (legacy code, not my idea) from before the thread handle is gotten.

Comment: @RichardCritten  Like I said, I hate it too.  I have heard the risks, and raised them ,but have been unable to get the rest of the group to refactor to that extent ( the thread is a wrapper around a DLL out of our control that can get hung.  The intent is to abandon it if it gets hung) .  As noted, the issue here happens *without* the `TerminateThread` getting called.  A non-hung thread.

Comment: Just to move the conversation away from the `TerminateThread` that never got executed, I tried commenting out that line, and the exception continues to get thrown,

Comment: Is it possible that hThread was never the right handle in the first place? I.e., your WaitForSingleObject was not actually waiting on the thread; it was waiting on somebody else's handle, which got closed in the meantime.

Comment: @RaymondChen The return result for `WaitForSingleObject` was zero, which per the API means `WAIT_OBJECT_0` meaning "The state of the specified object is signaled".  Debugger says the value of hThread is not 0 or -1L.  Now looking at the doc for `_beginthread` I now see this remark "If the thread that's generated by _beginthread exits quickly, the handle that's returned to the caller of _beginthread **might be invalid** or point to another thread."  Maybe I'll answer my own question based on that.  Thanks for triggering some deeper introspection

Comment: WFSO returning WAIT_OBJECT_0 doesn't prove that hThread refers to your thread. Maybe it refers to an event that is signaled, or a file whose I/O has completed. You didn't show the code that initializes hThread so we don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments by Raymond Chen, I investigated whether the handle I was using might be invalid, and was surprised to find that Microsoft actually says the thread creation API `_beginthread()` can actually return an invalid handle or the handle of another thread.

The `WaitOnSingleObject()` seems to think the handle is OK.  But Microsoft does warn on undefined behavior if a thread handle is closed during the wait.  So lets leave open the possibility of undefined behavior there.

Microsoft's documentation on threads recommends using `_beginthreadex()` instead of `_beginthread()` if validity of handles is important.

Raymond adds to this by noting another section that says
"_endthread automatically closes the thread handle, whereas _endthreadex does not. Therefore, when you use _beginthread and _endthread, do not explicitly close the thread handle by calling the Win32 CloseHandle API. This behavior differs from the Win32 ExitThread API."

Comment: Oh, you're using `_beginthread`. That function is [explicitly documented as](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx) "when you use _beginthread and _endthread, do not explicitly close the thread handle by calling the Win32 CloseHandle API."